# Python mysql parameters and load data command

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

What am I doing wrong here?

```py
import pymysql, os

directory = os.path.join('path', 'to', 'directory')
filename = 'my_filename.csv'
filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
to_table_name = "my_table"

connection = pymysql.connect(..., local_infile=True)
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    load_statement = """
    load data local infile %s
    into table %s
    fields terminated by ','
    optionally enclosed by '"'
    lines terminated by '\\n'
    ignore 1 lines
    """
    cursor.execute(load_statement, (filepath, to_table_name, ))
connection.commit()
connection.close
```

I get the following error message:

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\'my_table\'\n    fields terminated by \',\'\n    optionally enclosed by \'"\'\n    lines\' at line 2')
```

I want to load my file into a mysql database.

I've tried `cursor.execute(load_statement % (filepath, to_table_name))` but to no avail...any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Solen'ya you mean `connection.commit()` I've done that

Comment: Is your mysql command working in terminal or shell ? Please try that first.